# Как определить наличие слова в тексте?

Tags: php

как можно в php определить наличие определённого слова в тексте?

Comment: Минус за полное отсутствие самостоятельной попытки найти решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял то вы хотите найти подстроку в строке. Это можно сделать методом strpos.

```
// строка в которой вы ищете слово
$mystring = 'Текст с 4 словами';
//слово, которое вы ищете
$findme   = 'Текст';

$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

if (false === $pos) {
    echo 'слово ' . $findme . ' не найдено';
} else {
    echo 'слово ' . $findme . ' найдено в позиции ' . $pos;
}
```

Кроме этого вы можете решить эту задачу, используя регулярные выражения. Или же можно написать свой метод для поиска подстроки в строке.
Но для простых вещей, я использую именно strpos.